# python str() and unicode() producing different results in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, unicode

I have a script which takes in an input JSON and uses pandas DataFrame to produce some output.

Here is an excerpt from the script - observe the inline comments:

```
model = u"ABC123010"  
log.info(model)  # ABC123010
tafs_df = pd.DataFrame(tafs)
tafs_df['market']=str(model)
tafs_df['market2']=unicode(model)
log.info(tafs_df['market'])  # ABC123010
log.info(tafs_df['market2'])  # ABC12301
```

It seems if I store a unicode value in a pandas dataframe it truncates the last character, but string works just fine.

I assume this is somehow related to pandas dataframe, not `unicode` or `str` directly.

Is there an explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: It shows the correct values if you just log/print the results of the function calls directly?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you mean the output of `str()` and `unicode()` calls? Yes. It is producing the correct output: `ABC123010`

Comment: What kind of object is `model`? In Python 2, objects can define a `__unicode__` method...

Comment: You need to provide [MCVE] - without a `model` answers will be pure speculations.

Comment: @Blckknght and @Rogalski, my apologies... I've edited the post to demystify what kind of object is `model`. Basically, it is a set of unicode characters.

Comment: what is `log`? what is `tafts`  definately can't reproduce your issue